# Can iOS Settings app Documents & Data show incorrect usage?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm at a state where, on my iPhone, my App's Shared Group Container Directory is Using 303 KB, Documents Directory is Using 16 KB, Temporary Directory is Empty, and, Caches Directory is using 295 KB.

Yet, for some reason my iPhone's Settings App > General > iPhone Storage, seems to think that my app's "Documents & Data" is using 191.9 MB. By my calculation it should not be using more than 614 KB. What gives?

I have tried everything I could think of here. I tried downloading my app's container to my Mac using Xcode. I have even tried re-booting my iPhone, and force-quitting & restarting the iOS Settings app. None of these have offered a hint.

Is there something I'm missing here? How exactly does the system calculate "Documents & Data" disk usage? Is there anyway to know what using this disk space?

Comment: Same here, "Documents & Data" shows 3.8GB and container size is only 24MB.